# Symfony 4 create a task in a specific project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm a beginner in symfony and i have an issue who i'm suppose is super easy to find but i can't . So i'm using symfony 4 , i create two entities : Project and Task.  A project can have two or more tasks but the tasks is only link with 1 project .

For exemple , I can  have a project call :"go to japan" and my tasks will be "find a place to stay", "booking the ticket" etc etc

So i create my entity with a ManyToOne relation . I use the maker to create the crud and change it a little .

So for now , i can CRUD a simple project and I can CRUD task . Now i want when i create my task from a project , he know which project is . (for example we are in the project "go to japan" and when i create a task" he know that we are in "go to japan" )

So in my twig template , i succed to put a list of the task from the current project and a button to create a new task . When i click on it , i have the form with i select choice of projects . Everything works but i don't want to people choose the project , i want for the choice of the select is automatically know which project we are .

Ah , also i succed to in the task show the id of the project . I pass it on a route , there the code i have :

In my controller task :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/new", name="ptask_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request,ProjectRepository $projectRepository): Response
{

    $id = $request->query->get('id');

    $ptask = new Ptask();

    $form = $this->createForm(PtaskType::class, $ptask);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($ptask);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('ptask_index');
    }

    return $this->render('ptask/new.html.twig', [
        'ptask' => $ptask,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'id' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

In my twig project : `<a href="{{ path('ptask_new',{'id': project.id}) }}">Add a TODO task </a>`

In my twig task there are only a link for the form :

````
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}```
````

In my form ,tasktype :

```
class PtaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ptaskname')
            ->add('ptaskposition')
            ->add('ptaskprojet',EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Project::class,
                'label'     => 'Projet',
                'choice_label' => 'projectname'

        ])

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ptask::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't know if i need to give you an other code , if so please tell me . May be my code aren't really good sorry .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the query builder in order to do this. Here is the documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

```
$builder->add('ptaskprojet', EntityType::class, [
'class' => Project::class,
'label'     => 'Projet',
'choice_label' => 'projectname'
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where(/*WHAT EVER YOU NEED*/);
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to answer me  , i saw it in my search and i actually try to do it but it doesn't work and also I don't really know what i need to do ;

I try this :

```
 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                ->where('p.id > :id');}
```

And i try a simple one with`->orderBy('p.projectname', 'ASC')`
But it doesn't work , i have this error message :

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Form\PtaskType::App\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Form\EntityRepository, instance of App\Repository\ProjectRepository given, called in C:\wamp64\www\projectsymfony6\vendor\symfony\doctrine-bridge\Form\Type\EntityType.php on line 32
```

The line 32 of this file is :

```
$queryBuilder = $queryBuilder($options['em']->getRepository($options['class']));
```

I don't know why it's not working

Comment: based on this sentence `Everything works but i don't want to people choose the project`, i think you don't need to have `project` in your form, you can force it like this 
`$ptask = new Ptask();`
`$ptask->setProject($projectRepository)->find($id);`

Comment: thank you . Acctually i want to let also users choose the project but if they create from a project , i want to put in first the project where they are . But this code will help me so thank you